# Adjusting Scatter to move when objects are touched, and scatter only adding one object

Tags: raspberry-pi, kivy, raspbian

[image: Pi console and kivy GUI]Fooling around with Scatter, but Scatter is only showing one object, even though multiple buttons are added (see code) (If I move that button, there isn't another one under it!). 
Additionally, object does not move if I touch it and then move finger. Only moves the object when I touch the background around it (don't want background touches to interact! I want the box to move when I touch and drag it). How can I solve these  problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Each **Scatter** moves with all its children, so if you want to independent widgets to move on touch than you'll need two scatters

2) If your object inside the scatter captures input (like a button), than the Scatter won't get those events.

3) If you don't want the Scatter to have a "background", make the scatter the same size as its children

```
<SomeScatter@Scatter>:
    Button: #or another type of image
        size: root.size
```